# Splitting Paragaraph to sentences in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract sentences from a paragraph using regex. Please note I'm trying to acheive this using java script. I tried out some ways done in other languages, resulted in syntax errors. I would like it not to consider titles like Mr.,Mrs. etc.. as end of sentences. Also to be sensitive to strings like "Michel G." and not to interpret it as an end of sentence. Please find my regex below. I tried many methods but still couldnt get it working. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var sentences = $(this).text()
.replace(/(((?![.!?]['".”]?\s).)*[.!?]['".”]?)(\s|$)/g,
'<span class="sentence"> $1 </span> $3<div class="commentform">' + formdialog + '</div>');
```

Paragraph to be extracted

“He is trying to give a push,” said a senior American official, who spoke on the condition of anonymity because of the delicacy of the matter, adding that the talks were bogging down “both because of short-term irritants and slowness at getting at fundamental issues.” Mr. Kerry was a tireless prod and a frequent presence in Jerusalem and Ramallah leading up to the resumption of talks in July, and he has recently met for hours at a time with Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu of Israel and the Palestinian Authority president, Mahmoud Abbas, in neutral sites like New York, London and Rome. Now, after a brief period of dealing with other problems, he is returning to the region to throw himself back into the process.

Michael R. Gordon contributed reporting from Riyadh, Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, yes. You're [not doing bad](http://regexr.com?376je), but the problem you're facing is when a dot *doesn't* end a sentence, like in `Mr. Kerry` and `Michael R. Gordon`. There is no easy solution for that, I'm afraid.

Depending on what you know about the paragraph you're extracting, you could try disallowing a match after a single letter followed by a dot and common abbreviations followed by a dot, but then you're still going to trip up on 'mr. Kerry spoke to the president.' and 'where do you think you're going, mr.'
So you will have to decide how bad false positives (split in two while it was actually one sentence) and flase negatives (not split when it should've been) are and adjust your solution accordingly.

Please note that this is a **hard** problem.
Often, word processors like OpenOffice and Word try to detect when a sentence has ended to automatically convert the following letter to uppercase. Most keyboards for smartphones try to do this as well. I've never encountered any that do this perfectly; examples like the ones I gave trip them up.